# Null Pointer Exception @ stopService()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

In my application I am starting a service like this :

```
startService(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, GetContactService.class));
```

and after starting the service I move on to another activity, and from the button click in that I have started an Asyctask like this :

```
class ABC extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        // my code snippet
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // my code snippet
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //stopping the service which I have started earlier
        stopService(new Intent(TelaSketchUtil.this, GetContactService.class));
    }
}
```

But here it runs fine till do in Background, but on the stopService line in the Post Execute it gives a Null Pointer Exception as:

LogCat:

```
04-23 15:25:21.705: W/dalvikvm(26710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b547210)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3146)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at com.telasketch.misc.TelaSketchUtil$GetContactNumber.onPostExecute(TelaSketchUtil.java:225)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at com.telasketch.misc.TelaSketchUtil$GetContactNumber.onPostExecute(TelaSketchUtil.java:1)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 15:25:21.715: E/AndroidRuntime(26710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
```

Comment: check this class TelaSketchUtil.java line number :225 ans show us SplashScreen.java code...

Comment: @DhawalSodha yeah this crashes in stop service in post method. But my question still remain same.

Comment: check service is started or not?? and which is line number 225 in TelaSketchUtil.java??

Comment: Yes service is started.. then only I am able to do all my work.. but there is a  null ponter exception in stopService

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `TelaSketchUtil` class is an invalid `ContextWrapper`.

The problem occurs in [ContextWrapper.getPackageName()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-m-preview-2/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#130):

```
@Override
public String getPackageName() {
    return mBase.getPackageName();
}
```

Apparently, the `mBase` value is null.

Since you didn't post the code for it, my best guess is that your `TelaSketchUtil` class extends `ContextWrapper` directly, and does `super(null)` in the constructor. That will land you an instance that is pretty unusable as a `Context` arg.

It may also be some more subtle problem, like `TelaSketchUtil` subclassing something that defers its `ContextWrapper.mBase` initialization, with your `onPostExecute()` code running before that initialization. This seems unlikely to me, though, unless you're doing something very strange.